# Alternate for UNION in JPQL

Tags: spring, jpa, union

I have below query which return code and fcode from three different tables.

```
select c.code,a.familycode as fcode from test1 a ,test2 c
where a.code=c.code order by c.code
union
select c.code,b.familycode as fcode from test3 b ,test2 c
where b.code=c.code order by c.code
```

Since JPA doesnt support UNION , I need your help to implement the @query in JPA repository.
I dont want to use eclipselink for this implementation.I executed the above query in two different queries and merged.But it is too difficult for my logic to merge.

Comment: why is it too difficult to merge? You get a List<Object[]> from query 1, and a List<Object[]> from query 2, so you do addAll of the individual results to get the overall. Since you have no ORDER BY there is no need for relative ordering of the different query results

Comment: @neil  sorry I have order by c.code in both the queries

Comment: so put the results in a SortedSet and define a Comparator (and omit the order by from the query)

Comment: @Neil I can't because the result set code have duplicate and I need to put those result set in map like result having same code will be the key and corresponding fcode will be the list<string > value in Hashmap

Comment: No idea where a HashMap comes into anything here ... you return 2 columns, from 2 queries. You then sort them as required. Good luck